# Trying to send photo to PHP api endpoint using phonegap, file is empty

Tags: php, cordova, phonegap-plugins, file-transfer

I have a url on an existing website that is currently used to post files to.  It works the standard way (with a form where you browse for the file and then post it).  What i would like to do is use the phonegap/cordova FileTransfer object to upload the file.  I have some code which is almost exactly like the example code from the cordova documentation and it almost works but the file itself seems to be either missing or not referenced in the $_FILES variable on the PHP side.  As a test i added some logging to compare what this parameter looks like with a successful upload vs my phone upload.  here is what a var_dump gives me:

Success: var_dump($_FILE):

```
array(1) {
  ["policy_document"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(11) "whitley.pdf"
    ["type"]=>
    string(15) "application/pdf"
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    string(14) "/tmp/phpNrB6qB"
    ["error"]=>
    int(0)
    ["size"]=>
    int(451383)
  }
}
```

And here is a failure: var_dump($_FILE):

```
array(1) {
  ["file"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(17) "cdv_photo_017.jpg"
    ["type"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["error"]=>
    int(1)
    ["size"]=>
    int(0)
  }
}
```

I suspect it may have something to do with the request coming from another domain but not sure how to fix this.  Any ideas?

(note, i would show you my javascript but its exactly like this example here: http://zacvineyard.com/blog/2011/03/upload-a-file-to-a-remote-server-with-phonegap)

Answer (score 0):

I hate when this happens, but somehow i've fixed the problem and i have no clue why.  All i did was go into the php script and add a line to fwrite out the headers into my log file and all of a sudden it started to work.

shrug...

Comment: Or not... i've been testing this over and over and it works sometimes and other times it fails

Comment: Nailed it! (not that anyone cares).  I had a max upload file size in my php.ini of 2mb.  seems that the average pic on an iPhone 5s is somewhere between 1.7 and 2.3 mb which is why some were failing and others went through